# Why does this Keras implementation of the DDPG algorithm update the critic's network using the gradient but the pseudocode doesn't?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, keras, gradient-descent, ddpg, pseudocode

I'm trying to understand the DDPG algorithm using Keras

I found the [site](https://keras.io/examples/rl/ddpg_pendulum/) and started analyzing the code, I can't understand 2 things.

The algorithm used to write the code presented on the page

[image]

In the algorithm image, updating the critic's network does not require gradient

But the gradient is implemented in the code, why?

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    target_actions = target_actor(next_state_batch)
    y = reward_batch + gamma * target_critic([next_state_batch, target_actions])
    critic_value = critic_model([state_batch, action_batch])
    critic_loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.square(y - critic_value))

critic_grad = tape.gradient(critic_loss, critic_model.trainable_variables)
critic_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(critic_grad, critic_model.trainable_variables))
```

The second question is why in the photo of the algorithm when calculating the actor's policy gradient are 2 gradients multiplied by themselves and in the code only one gradient is calculated for the critic's network and it's not multiplied by the second gradient?

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    actions = actor_model(state_batch)
    critic_value = critic_model([state_batch, actions])
    # Used `-value` as we want to maximize the value given
    # by the critic for our actions
    actor_loss = -tf.math.reduce_mean(critic_value)

actor_grad = tape.gradient(actor_loss, actor_model.trainable_variables)
actor_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(actor_grad, actor_model.trainable_variables))
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this but it looks like to me that for the first question "minimizing the loss" means making a gradient descent step, thus we need to calculate the gradient. As for the second question, the algorithm looks like the expanded chain rule to me for the gradient of `critic_value(state_batch, actor_model(state_batch))`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your first question is because the line 'update the critic by minimising the loss $L = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i \left( y_i - Q(s_i, a_i |\theta^Q)\right)^2$ is implying that you will do this by using a gradient, i.e. you calculate the gradient of the loss wrt the parameters and perform a gradient descent step.

For the second question, I am not 100% sure because I don't use tensorflow but I would assume that in the automatic differentiation used it will do the multiplication automatically behind the scenes. In PyTorch I know that it automatically calculates the chain rule when you take the derivative, so it is likely to be a reason similar to this.